# Display summary data for every month in SQL for last 3 years

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have this T-SQL query that would be the total count of claims, dollar value for the date declared.

But I need to find the count and dollar value for each month beginning starting 2016 and until today / yesterday. I want to load the result set to a new table. Any thoughts or suggestions? Thanks in advance!

T-SQL query

```
DECLARE @AsofDATE AS DATE
DECLARE @AsofDateINT AS INT

SET @AsofDATE = '1/1/2018'      
SET @AsofDateINT = 20180101

SELECT  
    COUNT(S.ClaimNum) Count_of_Claims, 
    SUM(ReserveIndemnityAmount) AS RD_REserve,
    @AsofDATE AS AsofDate 
-- INTO #tempRD
FROM    
    (SELECT    
         f.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClaimNum ORDER BY f.ModifiedDate DESC) AS Row_order_desc
     FROM
         [dbo].[Snapshot] f
     WHERE     
         CAST(f.ModifiedDate AS DATE) <= @AsofDATE) S
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         ClaimKey, SUM( t.LossRsvAmt) AS ReserveIndemnityAmount  
     FROM  
         Stg.Claim_Transaction t  
     WHERE 
         TransactionDate < @AsofDateINT 
     GROUP BY 
         ClaimKey) T ON t.ClaimKey = s.ClaimID
WHERE   
    S.Row_order_desc = 1
    AND S.DerivedClaimStatus NOT IN ('Closed', 'Cancelled', 'Abandoned', 'Record only', 'Opened in error' )
    AND s.specialty = 'RD'
```

Current result:

```
Count_of_Claims     RD_REserve          AsofDate
-------------------------------------------------
    15317           112192.15           2018-01-01
```

Expected result:

```
Count_of_Claims     RD_REserve          AsofDate
-------------------------------------------------
    15317           112192.15           2017-01-12
    15567           111592.15           2017-01-11
    15356           15492.15            2017-01-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your AsofDate is hardcoded to return. Why not replace that with ModifiedDate?

so something like

```
select 
 count(s.claimnum) countofclaims
,sum(amount) amount
,cast(eomonth(modifieddate) as date) [asofdate]
from your query...

group by 
 cast(eomonth(modifieddate) as date)
```